# JavaFX treeview top level works but sub-folders have wrong directory?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I am trying to build a text editor for my first program project. I have the treeview on the left side and the tabpane on the right.  There is a textarea on the tab.  My intent is to display the contents of the file that is selected in the treeview, if it is a file, to the textarea. Sounds simple enough right?
I have been trying all day to get this to work and I can not figure it out.  Something is wrong and it is beyond my skill level.
Any advice is appreciated.  Thank you to all you help make this a fantastic educational platform!

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue
import javafx.fxml.FXML
import javafx.fxml.Initializable
import javafx.scene.control.Tab
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell
import javafx.stage.FileChooser
import javafx.stage.Window

class Controller implements Initializable{

@FXML
TextArea inputSpace
@FXML
Tab tabName
@FXML
TabPane tabPane
@FXML
TreeView fileTree

void openAndSetTab(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    if(file.canRead()){
        def openFile = new Tab()
        tabPane.getTabs().add(openFile)

        //set file name to tab title
        def dotPosition = file.name.indexOf('.')
        def fileName = file.name.substring(0,dotPosition)
        openFile.text = fileName

        //add file data to text area
        def inputArea = new TextArea()
        openFile.setContent(inputArea)
        def data = file?.getText()
        inputArea.setText(data)

        //bring to front
        openFile.getTabPane().getSelectionModel().select(openFile)
    }else{
        println('Cannot read...')
        println(file.absolutePath)
    }
}

void openFile() {
    //get file
    def chooser = new FileChooser()
    def file = chooser.showOpenDialog(Window.getResource('Main.java') as Window)

    openAndSetTab(file)
}

/**
 * save text data to file
 * and set title of tab
 */
void saveFile() {
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser()
    def data = inputSpace.text
    def file = chooser.showSaveDialog(Window.getResource('Main.java') as Window)
    if(data != null){
        file.text = ''
        file << data
    }

    //set tab title to saved file name
    int dotPosition = file.name.indexOf('.')
    def fileName = file.name.substring(0,dotPosition)
    tabName.text = fileName
}

/**
 * stackoverflow.com Answer
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278601/javafx-treeview-directory-listing
 * answered Jul 9 '16 at 6:46
 * Author: fabian
 * Original was using CheckBoxTreeItem, I updated code to my needs
 * @param inputDirectoryLocation
 */
void displayTreeView(String inputDirectoryLocation) {
    def tree = new GetTree()

    // Creates the root item.
    TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>(inputDirectoryLocation)

    // Hides the root item of the tree view.
    fileTree.setShowRoot(false)

    // Creates the cell factory.
    fileTree.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView())

    // Get a list of files.
    def fileInputDirectoryLocation = new File(inputDirectoryLocation)
    List<File> fileList = fileInputDirectoryLocation.listFiles()

    // create tree
    for (File file : fileList) {
        tree.createTree(file, rootItem)
    }

    fileTree.setRoot(rootItem)
}

@Override
void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    displayTreeView(System.getProperty('user.dir'))
    fileTree.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem>() {
        @Override
        void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem> observableValue, TreeItem treeItem, TreeItem t1) {
            def file = new File(t1.value.toString())
            if(file.isFile()){
                openAndSetTab(file)
            }
        }
    })
  }
}
```

I added the groovy jar to the classpath so that's why it looks wired.  It't the superset of java.  Love using it.  What am I doing wrong?

The GetTree class is as follows,

```
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem

 /**
 * stackoverflow.com Answer
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278601/javafx-treeview-directory-listing
 * answered Jul 9 '16 at 6:46
 * Author: fabian
 * Original was using CheckBoxTreeItem, I updated code to my needs
 */
 class GetTree {
 static void createTree(File file, TreeItem<String> parent) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        TreeItem<String> treeItem = new TreeItem<>(file.getName())
        parent.getChildren().add(treeItem)
        for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
            createTree(f, treeItem)
        }
    } else{//must be a file
        parent.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(file.getName()))
    }
  }

}
```

Projects folder is

- tetragrammaton

  - .idea

    -sub-directories.here
  - out

    -sub-directories.here
  - src

    - sub-directories.here

  testing.txt

  TetraGrammaton.iml

The only files that open in the textarea that is on the tab, is the 2 files, testing.txt and TetraGrammaton.iml.  The other directories open upon clicking but do not open in the textarea.

Comment: "Something is wrong" is not enough information. Also make your code [mcve] please.

Comment: The `GetTree` class is not posted but it may contain your error. On the other hand it's hard to tell, if this is an issue, since you don't describe the issue in a way that helps narrow down the issue (we only know that there is an issue; there is no description of the expected and actual results). Please [edit] the question and improve it.